# Add Overlay to ionic QR reader

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Hello I'm doing a QR reader in ionic and I need to show the camera like this:

[image: Background image]

I used this plugin:
https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git

I need help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ideas to get a solution:

- Modify the exitsting plugin
- Write your own plugin
- There is an existing in place camera plugin: https://github.com/westonganger/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/tree/skanygin You could merge this one to gether with an javascript qr reader.